# How to fire dblclick event on a specific row in DataTables from inside 'initComplete'

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to fire a dblclick event programmatically from inside the `initComplete`code to select randomly a row the first time the page is show. Here is a sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({

        // The data is comming from ajax

        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            var table = this.api();
            var nrows = table.rows().count();
            var nr = parseInt(Math.random() * nrows);

            var event = new Event('dblclick');
            table.row(nr).node().dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    });

    table.on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
        alert('dblclick event has been fired!');
    }
```

However, the event is never fired.

Comment: Try adding the event to your table before doing the .DataTable() code, in other words, flip your code blocks around in document ready

Comment: `$(table.row(nr)).trigger('dblclick');` Better still, put your logic in a function which you call directly. Throwing fake events around will be a weak point of any logic.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything inherently wrong with your code.  I'd try wrapping the last two lines of your `initComplete` handler in a `setTimeout()` call. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: @user9263373 what you trying achive? after double clicking that row?.

Comment: @user9263373 You want select any random row???

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've added my own answer based on these comments. And @user9263373 this is a table that has an associated infobox from Wikipedia. When the user double-clicks on a row the Wikipedia infobox is refreshed. It is nice that when the webpage is opened the script selects randomly some row to refresh the infobox.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everybody for the comments. As suggested by @rory I put the logic of the event in a separate function like this:

```
function myDblClickEvent(table, self) {
    alert('dblclick event has been fired!' );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({

    // The data is comming from ajax

    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        var table = this.api();
        var nrows = table.rows().count();
        var nr = parseInt(Math.random() * nrows);

        myDblClickEvent(table, table.row(nr).node());
    }
});

table.on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
    myDblClickEvent(table, this);
}
```